Why does Deepin OS not show WiFi as expected?
I am a new user of Deepin OS. I had a problem, WiFi wouldn't appear or be detected even though I had installed the driver.
I use a Dell Latitude E5510 laptop.
when I check in the Terminal with the code lspci | grep -i network it appears:
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01).

Below I also provide several screenshots on my Deepin OS:



Using a (temporary) internet connection — Ethernet, USB tethering from your phone, other… — you can install the proprietary drivers (and firmware) for the Broadcom BCM4313.
Open the Terminal (e.g. CTRL+ALT+T) and run:
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms

Reboot.
Welcome to the great DeepinOS.
